# Detected use of different schedulers when testing with coroutines

Tags: unit-testing, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

I have a class that takes a coroutine dispatcher as a parameter that I am trying to test. In my tests I use `@Before` to setup my class before each test is run

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalCoroutinesApi::class)
@Before
fun setup() = runTest {
    .....
    val dispatcher = StandardTestDispatcher(testScheduler)
    scheduleService = ScheduleService(dispatcher)
}
```

I have a test that I am trying to run that has a `SharedFlow` that I want to check the value of so I also use `runTest` with that test

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalCoroutinesApi::class)
@Test
fun testFullScheduleCreation() = runTest{
    ......
    val data = scheduleService.scheduleChangedListener.first()
}
```

When I try to run the test I get an error

> Detected use of different schedulers. If you need to use several test
> coroutine dispatchers, create one TestCoroutineScheduler and pass it
> to each of them.

The error is because of my use of `@Before` but I am not sure how to fix the error without copying all code in that setup method to each test

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a few ways to share a dispatcher between tests. The simplest is to call `Dispatchers.setMain(...)` in your setup. If the main dispatcher is set to a `TestDispatcher`, the `runTest` function will use it for all subsequent tests.

```kotlin
@Before
fun setup() {
    val dispatcher = StandardTestDispatcher()
    scheduleService = ScheduleService(dispatcher)
    Dispatchers.setMain(dispatcher)
}
```

If you use this approach, you should also call `Dispatchers.resetMain()` in a test teardown function.

If you prefer to do it manually, you can also pass the dispatcher to `runTest`.

```kotlin
lateinit var dispatcher: TestDispatcher

@Before
fun setup() {
    dispatcher = StandardTestDispatcher()
    scheduleService = ScheduleService(dispatcher)
}

@Test
fun myTest() = runTest(dispatcher) {
    ...
}
```

As an alternative, you can also call `scope.runTest` to use a shared scope that contains a dispatcher.

```kotlin
lateinit var scope: TestScope

@Before
fun setup() {
    val dispatcher = StandardTestDispatcher()
    scope = TestScope(dispatcher)
    scheduleService = ScheduleService(dispatcher)
}

@Test
fun myTest() = scope.runTest {
    ...
}
```